I want my Visual Studio 2022 ASP.NET web project running on a Windows computer to be opened on the ip of my own windows machine, not on localhost
When I run the open source web project that I opened in Microsoft Visual Studio 2022 on my Windows device, it runs on localhost:5001 port in the Chrome browser, but when I run this project, I want my device to receive it via IP.
For example, I want it to be 192.168.192.130:5001 because I want to access and look at it from another device on the same network. Since it runs on localhost, I cannot access the web project even though it is on the same network. Even if I open the port in the firewall, I cannot access it.
My problem now is to take the IP address of this web project to the IP of my own device, as I said. My open source project is nopcommerce and I downloaded the source codes from its website.
In Visual Studio 2022, I tried to change my web project in the properties section so that it receives the IP address of the machine instead of localhost, that is like 192.168.192.130, but I could not find how to change it. I don't know how to do this because I don't know how to use Visual Studio.
enter image description here

Regarding how to configure the project to open in your own IP address, try the following steps:
1: Open the IISExpress configuration folder, usually in C:\Users[Your Username]\Documents\IISExpress\config.
2: Find and open the applicationhost.config file. Find the  section and find the site entry you want to configure, modify the  section and replace localhost with your local IP address.
3: Open the administrator command prompt and run the following command to register the IP address:

netsh http add urlacl url=http://192.168.192.130:5001/ user=everyone

4: Continue to run the following command in the administrator command prompt to allow the firewall to pass the specified port:

netsh advfirewall firewall add rule name="IISExpressWeb" dir=in protocol=tcp localport=5001 profile=private remoteip=localsubnet action=allow

5: Open Visual Studio 2022, right-click your project>Properties>Web>Server>IIS Express, and change the project URL to your local IP address and port.
For more details, please refer to this post:
Browse Web Site With IP Address Rather than localhost

You should edit the "applicationhost.config" in your project.
Also, you must run VS 2022 as administrator.
To edit your launch settings you migh also want to read here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/iis/development-time-iis-support?view=aspnetcore-9.0#iis-launch-profile
